# Ember-Data recursive hasMany association

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Has anyone used ember-data to model a tree of data?

I would assume it would be something like:

```
Node = DS.Model.extend({
    children: DS.hasMany(Node),
    parent:   DS.belongsTo(Node)
});
```

However, I have not been able to get this working which leads be to believe that either: 1) I'm just plain wrong in how I'm setting this up or, 2) it is not currently possible to model a tree using ember-data.

I'm hoping that it's the former and not the latter...

Of course it could be the JSON...I'm assuming the JSON should be of the form:

```
{
    nodes: [
        { id: 1, children_ids: [2,3], parent_id: null },
        { id: 2, children_ids: [], parent_id: 1 },
        { id: 3, children_ids: [], parent_id: 1 }
    ]
}
```

Any tips/advice for this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? Could you please add some code to your question to show us the problem?

Comment: Sure, I set up a simple [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/heuristocrat/5aqHx/) that shows how I believe I should be defining the model and then doing a search for a root node and attempting to access the children (which is where things break down).

Comment: That's a useful fiddle. I've had similar issues myself in a non-recursive hasMany, so I'm interested in seeing any solutions.

Answer (score 14):

There are several little things that prevent your fiddle to work:

- the `DS.hasMany` function asks for a String as argument. Don't forget the quotes: `DS.hasMany('Node')`
- in the fixture definition, `hasMany` relationships should not be postfixed by `_ids` or anything. Just use the plain name. For instance: `{ id: 42, children: [2,3], parent_id: 17 }`
- the `length` property of `DS.ManyArray` should be accessed using the `get` function: `root.get('children.length')`
- by default, the fixture adapter simulates an ajax call. The `find` query will populate the record after waiting for 50ms. In your fiddle, the `root.get('children.length')` call comes too early. You can configure the fixture adapter so that it makes synchronous call:

  ```
  App.store = DS.Store.create({
      revision: 4,
      adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter.create({
          simulateRemoteResponse: false
      })
  });
  ```

  Or you can load data to the store without any adapter:

  ```
  App.store.loadMany(App.Node, [
      { id: 1, children: [2, 3] },
      { id: 2, children: [], parent_id: 1 },
      { id: 3, children: [], parent_id: 1 }
  ]);
  ```
- and last one: it seems like the Ember app should be declared in the global scope (no `var`), and Ember-data models should be declared in the app scope (replacing `var Node = ...` by `App.Node = ...`)

Full example:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 4
});

App.Node = DS.Model.extend({
    children: DS.hasMany('App.Node'),
    parent:   DS.belongsTo('App.Node')
});

App.store.loadMany(App.Node, [
    { id: 1, children: [2, 3] },
    { id: 2, children: [], parent_id: 1 },
    { id: 3, children: [], parent_id: 1 }
]);

var root = App.store.find(App.Node, 1);

alert(root.get('children'));
alert(root.get('children.length'));
```

Comment: assuming App.Node has an attribute "name", is it possible to iterate over all children in a template like this:  {{#each child in controller.children}}{{child.name}}{{/each}} ?

Comment: How would you delete a Node without encountering an infinite recursion? I'm currently facing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This didn't work for me until I set up the inverse:

```
App.Node = DS.Model.extend({
    children: DS.hasMany('App.Node', {inverse: 'parent'}),
    parent:   DS.belongsTo('App.Node', {inverse: 'children'}) });
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in ember-data 1.0.0-beta.7 (last version). Did anyone resolved this in the lastest versions?

Answer (score -3):

Not sure but as per example given in ember guide

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});
```

The JSON should encode the relationship as an array of IDs:

```
{
  "post": {
    "comment_ids": [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```