# How to create has_and_belongs_to_many relationship with Ember.js & ember-data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, has-and-belongs-to-many, ember-data

Is it possible to create a hasAndBelongsToMany relationship with Ember.js & ember-data?

**Edit:** Added ActiveRecord model examples to clarify.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end
```

I have an associative table "projects_tags" linking project_id <=> tag_id.

Comment: I suppose you're asking about modeling a graph? Requisite functionality being asked about here (modeling a tree): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11997066/ember-data-recursive-hasmany-association (I upvoted)

Comment: @pauldechov that post may be along the same lines of what I'm trying to achieve — I'm not too sure. I've added some ActiveRecord model examples of what I'm attempting to accomplish. Sorry for the lack of information originally.

Comment: There is no explicit HABTM in Ember.  Here are the supported associations: https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/associations

You might try a has_many with an intermediate node/table similar to @pauldechov suggestion.

Edit: Actually since the intermediate has_many would require an ID (in the rails way of thinking), I'm not sure that would work at all. :/

Comment: Would a "has_many :through" relationship work?

Comment: I've posted a kind of answer here, perhaps it could help for now, since many-to-many have not yet built-in support in ember-data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299924/emberdata-two-models-related-with-hasmany-relationships

Answer (score 4):

In this example, I'd suggest embedding the tags in the Post, so that the resulting structure looks like this

```
{
   title: "some post",
   tags: [ "tag1", "tag2" ]
}
```

This is generally good practice when you don't need to have additional value on the relation. If you want to have the `Tag` model on the client, you can still do it via embedding.

```
{
   title: "some post",
   tags: [ { name: "first tag" }, { name: "second tag" } ]
}
```

in this case you could specify it as an embedded relation, such as this

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr("string"),
  tags: DS.hasMany("App.Tag")
});

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr("string"),
  post: DS.belongsTo("App.Post")
});

App.store.adapter.serializer.map("App.Tag", {
  tags: { embedded: 'load' }
});
```

keep in mind that embedding only works in Ember Data revision 10. It is not supported in 5-9.

**Most of the time you don't really want to model everything the same way as you would model it in a relation database.**

You should lean towards NoSQL-ish JSON, which generally means embedding things, rather than making complex associations. The reason for this is that your database can `JOIN` data very efficiently, especially with indexes, but doing this over the network is a bad idea because it results in a lot of requests.